# Posting json array with strings to Asp.Net MVC action controller is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, binding, model

I cannot get Asp.Net MVC to bind a list of strings sent as an json object unless I wrap them in a class. I have a hard time believing that it is a must to wrap the list like that. Been looking at various examples and what not for a few hours, but cannot get any other solution to work. What am I missing? Working and non-working code below.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: "keyapi/activate.json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "keys": [ "1", "2" ] }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
    }
});
```

When using an action controller such as the one below "keys" will be null.

```
[HttpPost]
public Response<List<string>> ActivateKeys(List<string> keys)
{
    return KeyService.ActivateKeys(test.Keys);
}
```

If I add a class to wrap the list it works. Am I forced to do so, or am I missing something here? The code below works, using the same jquery post code.

```
[HttpPost]
public Response<List<string>> ActivateKeys(Test test)
{
    return KeyService.ActivateKeys(test.Keys);
}
public class Test
{
    List<string> Keys { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest two things

1) Replace

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "keys": [ "1", "2" ] }),
```

by

```
data: JSON.stringify([ "1", "2" ] ), // <-- Send the array directly
```

doing this you'll be passing an array as parameter instead of an object containing an array propery named `keys`

2) If previous suggestion alone doesn't work, replace

```
ActivateKeys(List<string> keys)
```

by

```
ActivateKeys(IList<string> keys) // <-- Use interface IList<T>
```

as not 100% sure if mvc engine would be able to resolve to `List<string>`

Comment: Your first suggestion worked wonders. No need to use the interface. So there's no need to map the array to the parameter name. Why is that?

Comment: Because mvc engine will try to convert your exact json object to method parameter, if you add an extra level to define `keys`, it will assume this is parameter property and not the name of the parameter.